# Is this the correct way to calculate Bhava Dig Bala?

Tags: astrology

example in javascript

```
const NARA_POINTS = 60;

const getNaraSign = (ascSign: number, ascSignDeg: number) =>
  [3, 6, 7].indexOf(ascSign) !== -1 || (ascSign === 9 && ascSignDeg < 15);

const getJalacharaSign = (fourthSign: number, ascSignDeg: number) =>
  [4, 12].indexOf(fourthSign) !== -1 || (fourthSign === 10 && ascSignDeg >= 15);

const getChatushpaadaSign = (tenthSign: number, ascSignDeg: number) =>
  [1, 2, 5].indexOf(tenthSign) !== -1 || (tenthSign === 9 && ascSignDeg >= 15);

export const getBhavaDigBala = (ascSign, ascSignDeg) => {
  const objScore = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 0,
    9: 0,
    10: 0,
    11: 0,
    12: 0,
  };

  const naraSign = getNaraSign(ascSign, ascSignDeg);
  if (naraSign) {
    objScore['1'] += NARA_POINTS;
    objScore['2'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
    objScore['3'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['4'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['5'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['6'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    //objScore['7'] = 0;
    objScore['8'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    objScore['9'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['10'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['11'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['12'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
  }

  let fourthSign = (ascSign + 3) % 12;
  if (fourthSign === 0) {
    fourthSign = 1;
  }
  const jalacharaSign = getJalacharaSign(fourthSign, ascSignDeg);
  if (jalacharaSign) {
    objScore['4'] += NARA_POINTS;
    objScore['5'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
    objScore['6'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['7'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['8'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['9'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    //objScore['10'] = 0;
    objScore['11'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    objScore['12'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['1'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['2'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['3'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
  }

  let tenthSign = (ascSign + 9) % 12;
  if (tenthSign === 0) {
    tenthSign = 1;
  }
  const chatushpaadaSign = getChatushpaadaSign(tenthSign, ascSignDeg);
  if (chatushpaadaSign) {
    objScore['10'] += NARA_POINTS;
    objScore['11'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
    objScore['12'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['1'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['2'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['3'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    //objScore['4'] += 0;
    objScore['5'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    objScore['6'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['7'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['8'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['9'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
  }

  let seventhSign = (ascSign + 6) % 12;
  if (seventhSign === 0) {
    seventhSign = 1;
  }

  const keetaSign = seventhSign === 8;
  if (keetaSign) {
    objScore['7'] += NARA_POINTS;
    objScore['8'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
    objScore['9'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['10'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['11'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['12'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    //objScore['4'] += 0;
    objScore['1'] += NARA_POINTS - 50;
    objScore['2'] += NARA_POINTS - 40;
    objScore['3'] += NARA_POINTS - 30;
    objScore['4'] += NARA_POINTS - 20;
    objScore['5'] += NARA_POINTS - 10;
  }
```